# Karate.get() method does not return default value when given jsonpath is not present

Tags: karate

Karate official document mentions that it returns null if variable/jsonpath is not found. The default value can be overriden using second argument.

When I tried this then for the absent variable I see it is giving null and able to override null. But the same did not go as expected for jsonpath expression. It gives #notpresent which is not overridden by the second argument.

**JSON Document**

```
{
"store": {
    "book": [
        {
            "category": "reference",
            "author": "Nigel Rees",
            "title": "Sayings of the Century",
            "price": 8.95
        },
        {
            "category": "fiction",
            "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
            "title": "Sword of Honour",
            "price": 12.99
        },
        {
            "category": "fiction",
            "author": "Herman Melville",
            "title": "Moby Dick",
            "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
            "price": 8.99
        },
        {
            "category": "fiction",
            "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
            "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
            "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
            "price": 22.99
        }
    ],
    "bicycle": {
        "color": "red",
        "price": 19.95
    }
},
"expensive": 10
```

}

```
// Working example with variables
* def df = 12
* def v741 = karate.get("df", "100")
* print "v741", v741 // output = 12 bcz variable 'df' exists
* v741 = karate.get("df1", "100")
* print "v741", v741 // output = 100 bcz variable 'df1' does not exists


// non-working example with jsonpath
* def v74 = karate.get("$jsonObject.store.book[1].author1", 100)
* print "v74", v74 // Output = #notpresent
```

[image]

More Update on the issue -

It is certainly a bug. Sorry, I reverted the accepted answer upvote.

```
* print karate.get("jsonObject.store.book[*].author", 100) // It should give an array of authors but gave 100.  
* print karate.get("$jsonObject.store.book[*].author", 100) // It gives an array of authors
```

You are saying "**In other words, use $ only when you want to run JsonPath "searches" or "queries**". As per doc, it should return the default value when jsonpath did not return a result.

Comment: you are really pushing the limits of karate. to be honest, `karate.get()` is designed to work mainly for direct variable names and then JS. that said, since you have not provided a working example, I request you to edit your question so I can try it - else I can't replicate this. this could very well be a bug in karate

Comment: Thanks, Peter for the reply. I have edited the question with a working example. I prefer to extract information through official documents always to create tutorials. Let me know if you need further details

Comment: sorry, I need the contents of `jsonObject`

Comment: Provided Json object.

Comment: now added answer

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a `$` and it will work as you expect:

```
* def v74 = karate.get("jsonObject.store.book[1].author1", 100)
```

In other words, use `$` only when you want to run JsonPath "searches" or "queries".

You are welcome to contribute a PR if you feel the docs need improving.

Comment: Thanks Peter. But I think consistency is missing here. If I do not use $ below -                                                  * print karate.get('jsonObject.store.book[*].title') -> It gives null. But in your solution above you are saying to ignore $. So it is not consistent when to use and when not to use.

Comment: @AMODMAHAJAN sorry I don't understand what is inconsistent. you are welcome to contribute code or docs

Comment: Certainly it is a bug/deviation from the doc. I have updated the description above. Sorry, I am not accepting this answer. Probably either we can update doc or fix the code. I will look into this and try.

Comment: @AMODMAHAJAN I still don't understand the confusion. there is a difference between JS and JsonPath. no worries, you do what feels right to you. maybe if you assume that `karate.get()` does NOT support JsonPath, you can move on :) - remember there is a dedicated API for JsonPath which is `karate.jsonPath()`